# Assigning a1<-1, a2<-2, a3<- using for loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to make

```
a1 <- 1
a2 <- 2
a3 <- 3
```

I want to use

```
for (i in 1:3) {
paste("a",i) <- i
}
```

but this clearly doesn't work.
Is there any way to this kind of stuff easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may need `assign` here

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(paste0("a",i), value =i)
}
```

NOTE: It is not recommended to create multiple objects in the global environment, instead we can keep them in a `list` or even  a named `vector` (in this case)

```
lst <- setNames(as.list(1:3), paste0("a", 1:3))
```